# call interval VBS or Batch

Tags: command-line, batch-file, updates, vbscript

I'm trying to code a simple chat program that runs from command line, which use a text file as the "database".
And I'm stuck when trying to create an autoupdate function while still listening for user input.
Is there a function to javascript's; setTimeout(functon(),int milliSec) in vbscript or batch?

Here is the function i would like to call every second:

```
Function read()
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
        ("c:\chat.txt", 1)
    Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
        txtOutput = objTextFile.ReadLine
        Wscript.Echo txtOutput
    Loop
    objTextFile.Close
End Function
```

or in  Batch:

```
:read
type c:\chat.txt
```

how can I call these when the command line is listening for input?

```
batch: set /p var="Say:"
vbs: WScript.StdOut.Write("Say:")
```

Comment: Ok, you can't do this in batch, however you can do something similar using the `choice /n /m "Say something?" /d n /t 1` In which case, the chat client would update every second and if the user hit `y` he could say something and the chat client would continue updating. The only thing is that the client will not update while the user is typing. If you want I could give you the full code. Just say so.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it VB.Net with a user interface instead. Works great now :) Thanks